# How to match exact Id within Comma seperated database column using LINQ and Lambda

Tags: linq, lambda

Hi I have SQL Table where I am storing values like this:

Column Name: Registration_ID

180,1801,1803,18011,220

180,1801,

180,1801,1803

No I want to match exact Registration_ID and get records based on the Registration_ID. I have tried Contains but is not matching exact values.

Here is my query:

```
var Result=db.Entity_StudentRepository.Get(x => 

x.Registration_ID.Contains(Used_For_Id.ToString())).Select(x => x.Registration_ID).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try the following query and let know if it works-

```
db.Entity_StudentRepository.AsEnumerable().Where(t=> Registration_ID.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Contains(Used_For_Id));
```